# How to export a value from a module?

Tags: node.js

This seems to be a simple problem, but the answers internet is cluttered with es5, babel, typescript, or legacy node 4 questions.

Question: How to export this:

```
**server.js**
class Server {

    constructor(port) {
        this._port = port;
    }

    start() {
        // Some code here.
    }

    stop() {
        // Some code here.
    }
}
```

To use it app.js **exactly** like this:

```
**app.js**
var Server = require("server");

var server = new Server(80);
server.start();
```

Pure Node 5 with ES6, no babel, or additional node packages. Just this.

Comment: How to export a value from a Node module hasn't changed (yet). It's the same no matter which Node version you use (which also determines the ES version). Your first step should always be to look at the documentation of the system itself: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html (which btw is one of the top results if I search for https://www.google.com/?q=how%20to%20export%20from%20node%20module).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export the class:

```
module.exports = Server;
```

And, if `server.js` is located in the same directory as `app.js`, you should use a relative path for `require()`, too:

```
// app.js
var Server = require("./server");
...
```

Comment: Nope: Error: Cannot find module 'server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (my\path\to\app.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:429:10)
 Press any key to continue...

Comment: So use `require('./server')`, as you should for local files. Or add the directory where `server.js` is located to `$NODE_PATH` (but this has nothing to do with _exporting_ per se).

Comment: Okay, thank you! Could you add the corrected import line "var Server = require("./server");" to your answer? If someone stumbles on this, he can directly see that this import is wrong in the first place.